# JQuery Number Counting - Slow down animation at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to achieve a counter,

So I found this working code here on Stack, however `$(this).stop` causes the count animation to bump back in value and then start again.

Maybe someone knows a better way of doing that.

In the end I would like to achieve like a ticking effect (small number increases) so easing is not an option.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.counter').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
          countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

        var animation = {
            countNum: countTo
        };

        $({ countNum: $this.text() }).animate(animation, {
            duration: 10000,
            step: function (now, fx) {
                $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                if (fx.pos > 0.5) {
                    $(this).stop();
                    $(this).animate(animation, {
                        duration: 10000,
                        step: function () {
                            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            $this.text(this.countNum);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="counter" data-count="1000000">0</h1>
<h1 class="counter" data-count="50">0</h1>
```

**Here is jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/r97nyb1p/